# Wildfly 9: Can't find hornetq-configuration.xml

Tags: java, jboss, server, wildfly, hornetq

The documentation about Hornetq says ([Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/#using-server.configuration)):

> The configuration directory is specified on the classpath in the run scripts run.sh and run.bat This directory can contain the following files.

but all I can find in my run.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Placeholder for people used to run.sh from older version redirecting them to read the readme
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo 
echo     ========================================================================================
echo 
echo To start JBoss Application Server please see $DIR/../README.txt
echo 
echo     ========================================================================================
echo
```

I also read something about ([Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/using-server.html#d0e763))

> HornetQ looks for its configuration files on the Java classpath.

but I could not find it in there as well.




I was browsing the web for quite a long time now but I could not find any more specific information about where this config file could be. Also there was no information about if there might be no path given and I have to put it in there myself (and how to).

Does someone know where this file might be or how I can define the path for it and write it myself? As the topic title says I'm using Wildfly 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WildFly you'll configure it through [WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Messaging+configuration). I'm guessing the `run.sh` is in reference to the standalone hornetq server. To start WildFly with messaging enabled you'll want to use:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Comment: Does it work adding the `transaction-timeout` in there? Or is it Wildfly specific configuration for Hornetq?

Comment: Following the `hornetq-configuration.xsd` i added the `transaction-timeout` into the `hornetq-server` configuration block and it seems to work.

Comment: I also found out that I can change most of it's (maybe all) values via the Wildfly admin console.

Comment: Yes the web console and CLI should be able to configure nearly all of it.